# A symmetrical number sequence

Tags: word, knowledge, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

**What 5-letter word does this sequence represent?**

---

```
      1000                   1000
       1000                 1000
        1000               1000
          999             999 
           999           999
             100       100
                1 1 1 1
```

Comment: rot13(ZVZVP) comes to mind, but doesn't explain quite enough.

Comment: @aschepler I see how you might got there, but no, not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer is:

> **[TEETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_tooth)**.
>
>  The image shows a top-down view of the teeth in the lower jaw. If the numbers are represented as Roman numerals, they identify the type of each tooth:
>
>  **I** is for **incisor**;
>  **C** is for **canine** and
>  **M** is for **molar**.
>
>  And the 999? Those are **pre-molars**, labelled as "one before molars", that is as 1000 − 1.

Comment: This was my first thought, though I couldn't make the connection.

Comment: Good job! This is the correct answer, and you explained it as intended.

Answer (score 4):

To me, this *sounds* like

> **minim**
>  a [musical note](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/minim)
>
>  A "symmetrical sequence" ought to produce a palindrome.
>  I can't quite make it work, but it seems like "ones in ems".
>
>  Also, the shape suggests the **minim**um of a graph.
>  And, a **minim** is called a 'half note' and half a sine wave (a perfect tone) is shown.

Comment: Nice attempt, but no this is not on the right track.